# React bootstrap alert not showing

Tags: react-bootstrap

React `react-bootstrap` alert not showing

```
import { Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import React from 'react';

const ShowSuccess= () => {
  return (
    <Alert color='primary' fade={false}>check it out!</Alert>
  );    
}

export { ShowSuccess };
```

and here is the part where my `alert box` is called

```
import { ShowSuccess } from '../../Notifications';

export const fetchInfo= async () => {
    try {
      await getData();
      ShowSuccess();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set a `flag` state to true whenever you made an API call. If the flag state is true then you can perform the necessary operation or task like showing an Alert box in your case else do the other task.

You can do the conditional rendering for displaying the alert box in JSX.

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from "react";

function FetchInfo(){
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {   
    async function fetch() {
      try {
        const data = await getData();
        setValue(data);     
        setFlag(true);
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
     fetch();
  },[])
   
  return (
   <> 
    {flag && 
     <Alert color='primary' fade={false}>check it out!</Alert>
    }   
  </>);
}
export default FetchInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the state for the Alert to work. It is a React component.
Include the component wherever you need to use the `Alert` and set it states after the API call is resolved.

```
function MyComponentWhereApiCallHappens() {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  async function apiCall() {
    const data = await fetchInfo();
    setShow(true); 
  }

  return (
     <div> 
       <Alert>
         /** alert content **/
       <Alert>
     </div>
  )
}
```

If you want to call something like an `Alert` from outside of the React component.

Use this library -> https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify